SIM の抜き差しでは LTEModemStatus の getStatus() は変化しない？
表記の件につきまして、LTEが接続できなくなった際に再接続する処理を行いたく、getStatus()の値を監視する処理をいれています。
ですが、LTE attach後にsimを抜きLTE接続ができない状態になってもLTE_READY(4)で固着しているようで遷移しません。
simの抜き差しではgetStatus()の値は変わらないのでしょうか？
お手数おかけしますが、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
以下がサンプルプログラムになります。
// libraries
#include <LTE.h>

// APN name
#define APP_LTE_APN "soracom.io" // replace your APN

/* APN authentication settings
 * Ignore these parameters when setting LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_NONE.
 */

#define APP_LTE_USER_NAME "sora" // replace with your username
#define APP_LTE_PASSWORD  "sora" // replace with your password

// APN IP type
//#define APP_LTE_IP_TYPE (LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V4V6) // IP : IPv4v6
#define APP_LTE_IP_TYPE (LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V4) // IP : IPv4
// #define APP_LTE_IP_TYPE (LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V6) // IP : IPv6

// APN authentication type
//#define APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE (LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_CHAP) // Authentication : CHAP
#define APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE (LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_PAP) // Authentication : PAP
// #define APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE (LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_NONE) // Authentication : NONE

/* RAT to use
 * Refer to the cellular carriers information
 * to find out which RAT your SIM supports.
 * The RAT set on the modem can be checked with LTEModemVerification::getRAT().
 */

#define APP_LTE_RAT (LTE_NET_RAT_CATM) // RAT : LTE-M (LTE Cat-M1)
// #define APP_LTE_RAT (LTE_NET_RAT_NBIOT) // RAT : NB-IoT

// initialize the library instance
LTE        lteAccess;

void setup() {
  char apn[LTE_NET_APN_MAXLEN] = APP_LTE_APN;
  LTENetworkAuthType authtype = APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE;
  char user_name[LTE_NET_USER_MAXLEN] = APP_LTE_USER_NAME;
  char password[LTE_NET_PASSWORD_MAXLEN] = APP_LTE_PASSWORD;

  // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  Serial.println("LTE networks scanner");

  /* Set if Access Point Name is empty */
  if (strlen(APP_LTE_APN) == 0) {
    Serial.println("This sketch doesn't have a APN information.");
  }
  Serial.println("=========== APN information ===========");
  Serial.print("Access Point Name  : ");
  Serial.println(apn);
  Serial.print("Authentication Type: ");
  Serial.println(authtype == LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_CHAP ? "CHAP" :
                 authtype == LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_NONE ? "NONE" : "PAP");
  if (authtype != LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_NONE) {
    Serial.print("User Name          : ");
    Serial.println(user_name);
    Serial.print("Password           : ");
    Serial.println(password);
  }

  while (true) {

    /* Power on the modem and Enable the radio function. */

    if (lteAccess.begin() != LTE_SEARCHING) {
      Serial.println("Could not transition to LTE_SEARCHING.");
      Serial.println("Please check the status of the LTE board.");
      for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
      }
    }

    /* The connection process to the APN will start.
     * If the synchronous parameter is false,
     * the return value will be returned when the connection process is started.
     */
    if (lteAccess.attach(APP_LTE_RAT,
                         apn,
                         user_name,
                         password,
                         authtype,
                         APP_LTE_IP_TYPE) == LTE_READY) {
      Serial.println("attach succeeded.");
      break;
    }

    /* If the following logs occur frequently, one of the following might be a cause:
     * - APN settings are incorrect
     * - SIM is not inserted correctly
     * - If you have specified LTE_NET_RAT_NBIOT for APP_LTE_RAT,
     *   your LTE board may not support it.
     * - Rejected from LTE network
     */
    Serial.println("An error has occurred. Shutdown and retry the network attach process after 1 second.");
    lteAccess.shutdown();
    sleep(1);
  }
}

void loop() {
      // LTE接続状態の確認
    if (lteAccess.getStatus() != LTE_READY)
    {
        lteAccess.shutdown();
        sleep(1);
        setup();
    }
}


SpresenseのArduinoのコードをみましたが simカードの挿抜をリアルタイムで検知はできないと思います。
getStatus()はclass LTECoreで内部変数_networkStatusを参照しています。ただし、これがセットされるタイミングが、beginやattachなどのアプリからの関数コールがきっかけなので、SIMの状態が必ずしも反映されるとはかぎらないようです。
class LTECore {
public:
・
・
  inline LTEModemStatus getStatus()
  {
    return _networkStatus;
  }
}

一方SDKの、lte_get_siminfo_sync()を使えば、SIM情報をcallbackで受け取れるようです。
Arduinoでもヘッダnuttx/wireless/lte/lte.hをincludeして、lte_get_siminfo_syncの第一引数optionに3GPPで定義のSIMカード情報を選択して利用します。（ここではMCCMNCとSPN指定）
■サンプル　追加部分抜粋
// libraries
#include <LTE.h>
#include <nuttx/wireless/lte/lte.h>

// APN name
#define APP_LTE_APN "******" // replace your APN
#define _ENA_SIMINFO_

#ifdef _ENA_SIMINFO_
extern "C"  int lte_get_siminfo_sync(uint32_t option, FAR lte_siminfo_t *siminfo);
extern "C"  int lte_get_errinfo(lte_errinfo_t *info);

lte_siminfo_t info = {0};

/* 
   Set the SIM information you want as an option
 */
uint32_t opt = LTE_SIMINFO_GETOPT_MCCMNC |
               LTE_SIMINFO_GETOPT_SPN;
#endif /* _ENA_SIMINFO_ */

#ifdef _ENA_SIMINFO_
static void print_siminfo(lte_siminfo_t *info)
{
  int i = 0;

  printf("[API] option:0x%0lX\n", info->option);
  if (LTE_SIMINFO_GETOPT_MCCMNC & info->option)
    {
      printf("[API] MCC:");
      for (i = 0; i < LTE_MCC_DIGIT; i++)
        {
          printf("%c", (char)info->mcc[i]);
        }
      printf("\n");
      printf("[API] mnc digit:%d\n", info->mnc_digit);
      printf("[API] MNC:");
      for (i = 0; i < info->mnc_digit; i++)
        {
          printf("%c", (char)info->mnc[i]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
  if (LTE_SIMINFO_GETOPT_SPN & info->option)     /* Get a SPN(Service Provider Name) */
    {
      printf("[API] SPN:");
      for (i = 0; i < info->spn_len; i++)
        {
          printf("%c", (char)info->spn[i]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
}

static void app_show_errinfo(void)
{
  int           ret;
  lte_errinfo_t info = {0};

  ret = lte_get_errinfo(&info);
  if (ret == 0)
    {
      if (info.err_indicator & LTE_ERR_INDICATOR_ERRCODE)
        {
          printf("err_result_code : %ld\n", info.err_result_code);
        }
      if (info.err_indicator & LTE_ERR_INDICATOR_ERRNO)
        {
          printf("err_no          : %ld\n", info.err_no);
        }
      if (info.err_indicator & LTE_ERR_INDICATOR_ERRSTR)
        {
          printf("err_string      : %s\n", info.err_string);
        }
    }
}
#endif /* _ENA_SIMINFO_ */

void loop() {
#ifdef _ENA_SIMINFO_
　　int ret;

    sleep(1);  /* Add a wait to suppress message output. */

    ret = lte_get_siminfo_sync(opt, &info);
    printf("[API] %s ret:%d\n", __func__, ret);
    if (!ret) {
      print_siminfo(&info);
    }
    else {
      /* Show info in case of error. */
      app_show_errinfo();
    }
#endif
・
・
}

※例ではエラー情報を取るためにlte_get_errinfo()もコールしています。
■出力ログ例
LTE networks scanner
=========== APN information ===========
Access Point Name  : ******
Authentication Type: CHAP
User Name          : ****
Password           : ****
attach succeeded.
[API] loop ret:0
[API] option:0xF
[API] MCC:440
[API] mnc digit:2
[API] MNC:10
[API] SPN:NTT DOCOMO
・
・
[API] loop ret:0
[API] option:0xF
[API] MCC:440
[API] mnc digit:2
[API] MNC:10
[API] SPN:NTT DOCOMO
[API] loop ret:-71　　　　　　　　　　　　<= SIMの切断後
err_result_code : 13
err_no          : -5
err_string      : Failed to get digit of MNC
[API] loop ret:-71
err_no          : -5
err_string      : Failed to get PIN status
[API] loop ret:-71
err_no          : -5
err_string      : Failed to get PIN status
[API] loop ret:-71
・
・

